# Rails fetching price using nokogiri and mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I am trying to fetch price from several website but I am unable to do so.For example right now I am trying from snapdeal but I am failing

```
module HomesHelper

  require 'mechanize'
    require 'nokogiri'


def scrape
mechanize=Mechanize.new
 page = mechanize.get('http://www.snapdeal.com/product/apple-iphone-6-16-gb/1270529654') 
 doc=page.parser
price= doc.css("div #buyPriceBox  span .payBlkBig selectorgadget_selected").text
puts price
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following scraping statement. Hope this works for you

```
 doc.css("div #buyPriceBox .pdp-e-i-PAY div.pdp-e-i-PAY-r span span.payBlkBig").text
```

Comment: I just only need price it is giving <span>Rs <span class="payBlkBig" itemprop="price">42,899</span></span>
<span class="payBlkBig" itemprop="price">42,899</span>

Comment: For me it is giving this : doc.css("div #buyPriceBox .pdp-e-i-PAY div.pdp-e-i-PAY-r span").text
 => "Rs 42,89942,899"

Comment: And also it is giving the same result twice

Comment: I have updated parsing logic a little bit to get exact answer. Please refer it.